# Which is more efficent Oracle SQL? PARALLEL CREATE TABLE AS SELECT or PARALLEL INSERT?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to back up tables and their data as part of software testing.  The exact tables and the data they contain may vary so I can't hard code the DDL or the data. The back up tables will have similar names as the original tables but with the prefix "QA_".  Similar, but not identical (except for the prefix), only because in order to work around the 31 character limit for table names I have to abbreviate some of the names.

Which would be the faster way of doing this?  Using a cursor object and looping through the tables to get their DDL like this:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(''TABLE'',' || '''' || cursor_rec.object_name || '''' || ') from dual
```

Using that DDL to create the backup tables and then populating those tables with:

```
INSERT /*+ parallel(' || new_table_name || 'DEFAULT) */ INTO '  || new_table_name  || ' SELECT  * FROM '  || table_name  || ''
```

Or doing a simple:

```
CREATE TABLE' || new_table_name 'PARALLEL AS SELECT * from ' || table_name || ''
```

Which is the faster of the two methods?

Comment: As we don't have your database, nor your hardware we cannot tell. Why don't you simply run the two versions on **your** database and time the difference?

Comment: I was speaking theoretically which method would be faster because I can't run these on data and tables that don't exist yet.   

Are there factors that I can consider beforehand in weighing which method to use?

Comment: you can always create some dummy tables to test this. Using SQL*Plus `autotrace` feature will then tell you which solution did more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, both `INSERT /*+ PARALLEL */` and `CREATE TABLE .... PARALLEL AS SELECT ...` are going to do direct load insert.  So, they are largely going to use the same code path, for the data loading.

CTAS will need to first do the DDL to create the table, before proceeding with the load.  But, that's a small amount of fixed work.  The larger the table being copied, the smaller factor that will be.

Finally, I'll just mention, that you should look into `NOLOGGING` to further improve performance.

On the CTAS, you can just add the `NOLOGGING` keyword after the `PARALLEL` keyword.  For the `INSERT /*+ PARALLEL */`, you'll need to first do an `ALTER TABLE ... NOLOGGING` to enable it.

Note that there are a few things you need to know, if you decide to go with `NOLOGGING`.  First, *only* direct-load will do nologging.  For tables, that means CTAS and INSERT with PARALLEL or APPEND hint.

Secondly, consider the recovery implications of `NOLOGGING`.  When a table is loaded with NOLOGGING option, the data is *NOT* logged to REDO.  So, you won't be able to recover the data in the table, unless you use a backup taken *after* the data was sucessfully loaded and committed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You won't be able to recover the data with a standby database either.

Answer (score 0):

[Create-table-as](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2159659) will generally be faster because it does not include many options, such as "primary keys, unique keys, foreign keys, check constraints, partitioning criteria, indexes, and column default values".

DBMS_METADATA by default will include most of those objects, which can significantly increase the time required to copy data.  (Although you may want those objects to exist for selecting, validation, etc.)